# Error onPostExecute with Html Parsing

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

My code is:

CikmisSorular.java:

```js
class CikmisSorular extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    String URL="http://www.utercih.com/rehberlik.aspx";
    String aciklama;
    String veri;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView txtWeb;
    Context mContext;

    CikmisSorular(Context c){
        this.mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle("Jsoup Uygulama.");
        dialog.setMessage("Veri getiriliyor");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document doc= Jsoup.connect(URL).get();//Siteye bağlantı sağlanıyor.
            Elements elements=doc.select("div[class=detayici]");//div tagına ait attiribute çağrılıp Element sınfının içerisindeki nesneye aktarılıyor.

            veri=elements.html();//istenilen html taglarını çeker.
            aciklama=Jsoup.parse(veri).text();//html taglarını texte çevirir.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void avoid)
    {
        TextView txtWeb1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_jsoup);
        txtWeb1.setText(aciklama);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I'm getting error:

> Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'

on `onPostExecute()` method.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in `onPostExecute`:

```
TextView txtWeb1 = (TextView)((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.tv_jsoup);
```